# How to use a field as a parameter in geospatial query on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

this is the query I would like to perform:

```js
    db.cells.find(
       {
         loc: {
            $near: {
               $geometry: {
                  type : "Point",
                  coordinates : [ 31.0, 31.0 ]
               },
               $minDistance: 0,
               $maxDistance: this.range
            }
         }
       }
    )
```

The problem is with `this.range`. I would like to use the field `range` of `cells` to set the max distance. This parameter can vary or `maxDistance` must be a fixed value for every document I try to match?

Comment: it should refer to the document. I saw that used in other clauses. My experience with mongo is limited so maybe I'm doing trivial mistakes.

Comment: You can't use `this` in `find` without [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

Comment: You can now find a way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014190/find-all-circles-that-intersect-a-given-point-with-a-mongodb-query/72080662#72080662)

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds to your issue is computing a distance field using `$geoNear` in aggregation pipeline. Then, use the computed distance field to compare with the max Distance you want(i.e. this.range in your case).

```js
db.cells.aggregate([
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          31.0,
          31.0
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "dist"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        lte: [
          "$dist",
          "$range"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TZbrNIPLKeq)